# Separate Jacoco coverage for integration tests in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I'm trying to get separate Jacoco coverage figures in SonarQube for unit & integration tests.

The [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Integration+Tests+for+Java+Project) describes using '**sonar.jacoco.itReportPath**', to distinguish integration tests, but it's deprecated and if I use the new '**sonar.jacoco.reportPaths**' then it all shows up as unit tests.

How do you get separate coverage figures in a non-deprecated way?

Answer (score 7):

Actually I've just found an [Jira Feature](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-345) via [Release Notes for Version 6.2](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+6.2+Upgrade+Notes), basically you can't get separate coverage metrics for unit and integration tests anymore.

Of course I've spent half the day digging in to documentation and only just found it minutes after posting the question :D